# common lisp function printing nil instead of ()

Tags: lisp, binary-tree, common-lisp

I have written a lisp function to make a complete binary tree from the provided list. The only problem is that it prints 'nil' instead of `()`. I need to make the function print `()`. A little bit of help will be really appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
(defun bst-add (item tree)
  (cond
   ((null tree) (list item '() '()))
   ((< item (first tree)) (list (first tree)
                (bst-add item (second tree))
                (third tree)))
   ((> item (first tree)) (list (first tree)
                (second tree)
                (bst-add item (third tree))))
   ;; element already exists in the tree:
   ;; do not put repeated, throw it away
   (t tree)
   )
  )

(defun make-cbtree (list)
  (let ((tree '()))
    (dolist (item list tree)
    (setf tree (bst-add item tree))
      )
    )
  )

(print(make-cbtree '(8 3 10 1)));==>(8 (3 (1 NIL NIL) NIL) (10 NIL NIL)) 
(print(make-cbtree '(8 3 10 1 6)));==>(8 (3 (1 NIL NIL) (6 NIL NIL)) (10 NIL NIL))
```

The expected output for `(8 3 10 1)` is `(8 (3 (1 () ()) ()) (10 () ()))` and the expected output for `(8 3 10 1 6)` is `(8 (3 (1 () ()) (6 () ())) (10 () ()))`.

Comment: Symbol `nil` and empty list `()` is the exact same object in Lisp: `(eq nil ())` evaluates to `t`.

Comment: @sds I know that, but how can I print () instead of nil here? I really need to print ()